# Java library to create an image file with data from a 2d array?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a nice-looking visualization of String data stored in a 2d Scala Array. I was wondering if a library exists to take a 2d String Array as input and write an image of a formatted table containing the data inside the 2d array to a file.

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** and being **on hold** because you didn't provide any research. And the "nice-looking visualization" is too broad.

Comment: ... and because [questions asking us to find a software library is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Try chart.js - it's got alot of rich looking visualisations and animates well.

Examples of use:

http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/area/radar.html
    http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/multi-axis.html

http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/doughnut.html

How to install, use and other information can be found on the main site below:
    http://www.chartjs.org

Comment: thanks, but this is JavaScript. I am looking specifically for a Java library